# Changing href of a link when another link is clicked (with JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<a id="id1" href="href1?key=value">First link</a>
<a id="id2" href="href2?key=value">Second link</a>
```

When the first link is clicked, I need to change the href of the second link to "href2" (and viceversa) with JQuery. Basically I need to reset the url, in such a way that there is not the query string:

- When "First link" is clicked, the second link has to become

  ```
  <a id="id2" href="href2">Second link</a>
  ```
- When "Second link" is clicked, the first link has to become

  ```
  <a id="id1" href="href1">First link</a>
  ```

**EDIT**

I'm using [an Ajax Tabs Content Script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/). In each tab I have a search form. For some reasons I have to pass the searched value via GET. It works, but if I change the tab, e.g. from tab 1 to tab 2, the search is repeated when coming back to tab 1. So I'm searching for a way to "reset" the url (i.e. deleting the query string) by clicking on the other tab.

I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: you mention change but change to what? you just said *"change the href of the second link (and viceversa)"*, sure that's easy but change to what? also what does *"**reset** the url"* mean?

Comment: Do you mean swaping href between each others??

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
​$("#id1").click(function(){
  $("#id2").attr("href") = "new_url";
});

$("#id2").click(function(){
  $("#id1").attr("href") = "new_url";
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I assume, both links will not trigger a full postback (i.e. refresh the page completely) because then, there would be no point in doing this on the client side with javascript. If the page does a full refresh, you will need to do this on your server.

---

EDIT: I see in your example your hrefs have a different format instead of "?" u are using "/", which might present problems, since there is no way to predict how many "/" can exist in a URL. However if you **know** that the parameters are after the **LAST** "/", then u can use that instead like so

```
$('#id1').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //To stop the postback (if needed)
   // Grab the url
   var url = $('#id2').attr('href');
   //Grab the substring from the start to the last index of "/"
   url = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf('/')); 
   //Get first part of url
   $('#id2').attr('href', url);
});
```

And this here is for urls with '?'

```
$('#id1').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //To stop the postback (if needed)
   // Split the href with '?' to get url without parameters
   var url = $('#id2').attr('href').split('?');
   //Get first part of url
   $('#id2').attr('href',url[0]);
});
```

Choose whichever suits you and do the same for the 2nd link

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the format I used, it's "?" instead of "/". Now it's right.

Answer (score 0):

try do do this-:

```
    $("input[id^='id']").each(function(){
 var href_value = $(this).attr("href");
      $(this).attr("href") = href_value;
    });
```